# How do you typically make your CPLEX Studio models more user friendly?

Tags: user-interface, cplex

Non-optimization question about CPLEX Studio....

So you make your awesome OPL model in CPLEX Studio and it brilliantly solves your amazeballs problem.

Suppose you wanted to allow other users to access this model in a nice user friendly way: Basically, specify some simple parameters in a simple user interface (without having to edit code etc), then, output the solution in some arbitrary way you coded up like an Excel file, HTML report, or whatever.

1) What are the options for a user interface, without adding in too much other technology?
(eg. I currently have a Java program doing exactly this, but I'd rather not rely on Java code / programmers / compiling / hosting source code etc)

2) What are the options for triggering some user friendly output, eg. in a standard format like Excel, some HTML report you coded up, or maybe just triggering a Python script, etc?
(eg. I currently render them in a Java FX application on grids, charts and HTML windows, I would prefer something more lightweight and accessible, like Python etc, HTML5 output)

3) In industry, what is the typical role of CPLEX in a production environment: Is it just called by an external application (Java/.NET etc), or is CPLEX Studio used more actively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are many options. You may write the model with an algebraic modeling language (AML) like OPL or a general purpose language. (GPL)

   If you use OPL then you may call your model from many GPL like C++, Java, Python ...

   Or you could plug that model in an existing application.
2. You could call OPL from Excel or DSX Python Notebook as can be read at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=306f3ded-33b8-4d9a-8568-b4288aa64265&ps=25
3. See the survey I mentioned in 1.
   Some users use CPLEX OPL IDE in order to make decisions and simulations
   Other use Decision Optimization Centre : https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-decision-optimization-center
   Finally, some write new applications from zero or plug the model into an existing application.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

Embed the optimisation model in wider business applications using Java, C#, Python, C++, whatever. Make it just part of the normal business systems that people use. It is just software. Make it so that the users really appreciate that the new software actually benefits them each time they use it. Make it easier to use the model than to not use it. Hide the model inside other software. Probably never even mention optimisation to your end users.

The best model in the world that could deliver amazing benefits will actually achieve nothing of practical value if it doesn't actually get used.

If your target audience or users have to do extra stuff or perform extra steps to use your model, then it will likely not get used very much and may wither and die. If they have to learn new applications etc to use it, it probably won't get used by most people.

By making your model part of their normal day-to-day processes, it will get used, and the practical benefits will come.

I have implemented and support a number of live optimisation applications in several large companies, making decisions that directly affect billions of pounds/dollars of products/revenues per year. Almost all of them have the real optimisation models totally hidden from the users, most of whom have no idea of optimisation or CPLEX; the software in their business systems just works.